# Specify tags using the x-amz-tagging request header

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-post

I have a Node program for file uploading to aws s3, I need to specify the x-amz-tagging with the request header. I tried something but it doesn't work!

```js
function buildRequestHeader() {
  return {
    'Content-Length': fileBuffer.size,
    'Content-Type': mimeType,
    'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
    'x-amz-tagging' :{"tag1":'abcd',"tag2":'efgh'}
  }
}
```

I have seen something from aws docs,

```js
PUT object-key?tagging HTTP/1.1
Host: examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com
Content-Length: length
Content-MD5: pUNXr/BjKK5G2UKExample==
x-amz-date: 20160923T001956Z
Authorization: authorization string
<Tagging>
   <TagSet>
      <Tag>
         <Key>tag1</Key>
         <Value>val1</Value>
      </Tag>
      <Tag>
         <Key>tag2</Key>
         <Value>val2</Value>
      </Tag>
   </TagSet>
</Tagging>
```

Could you please explain how it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code snippets you show are from two different methods of tagging, the first during [object creation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html), the second is [adding tags to an existing object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUTtagging.html).

The `x-amz-tagging` header is what you would use during object creation, but it uses a [different syntax](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html#put-object-specify-tags-example) than in your example.  Try this instead:

```
function buildRequestHeader() {
  return {
    'Content-Length': fileBuffer.size,
    'Content-Type': mimeType,
    'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
    'x-amz-tagging': 'tag1=abcd&tag2=efgh'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const fs= require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({'accesskey':'accesskeyvalue','region':'your s3 region'})

s3.upload(
  {
    Bucket: bucket_name,
    Key: key,
    Tagging: 'tag1=abcd&tag2=efgh',
    Body: fs.createReadStream('./filename.filetype'),
  }
```

this method is also working!!